# dictionary key with more than one value not printing all values

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a dictionary with repeated keys but different values for those keys and i want to pull all values for a specific key. Here is the abbreviated version of what I mean:

```
x_table = {'A':'GCT','A':'GCC','A':'GCA','A':'GCG'}

AA_list = [{'A'}]

for aa in AA_list:
    if aa in x_table:
        print x_table[aa]
```

For some reason it will only pull one of the values from x_table.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: a dictionary can not have repeated key.

Comment: A dict can only have have one value per key, you need to put all the different values in a list (or any container of your choice) and use this as the value.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary cannot have multiple entries for the same key.
Think about it - how were you planning on accessing the value?
what should `x_table['A']` return?  `'GCT'` or maybe `'GCA'`?

What you can do, is make a slight change to you data structure and save a list rather than a single values.
e.g.:  `x_table = {'A':['GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG'], 'B' = ['some', 'other', 'values']}`

In your example - you have only 1 key.  From the information you have posted I cannot tell if it is a small sample or the general case. If it is the general case, maybe a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) / [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) / [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) would serve you better: `('GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG')`

If you want to understand better *why* you cannot store multiple entries for the same key, you can read about it [in this link](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/).

Comment: thanks, that makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need define you dict structure like this:

```
x_table = {'A':['GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG']}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, a dictionary is implemented as a set.  As such, you ***cannot*** have multiple identical keys like so:

```
dict = {'a': 'blah', 'b': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}; // ''b would only have the value 'bar'
```

The way dictionaries are designed, they don't allow this.  They are basically hashmaps, and so allow quick access to the value via a key, but you can only have one key per value.  When you assign the second key, it overwrites the first.

You could, however, try implementing a dictionary as your value, like so:

```
x_table = {'A':{'a_1':GCT','a_2':'GCC','a_3':'GCA','a_4':'GCG'},'B':'blah'}
```

`AA_list = ['A']['a_1]`

Comment: What was wrong with this answer?